# This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I Am Getting This Error
**Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it**

And

**Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.**

This One

App.js file is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage'; 
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import './App.css'; 
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

class App extends Component {   render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={HomePage} exact/>
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );   } }

export default App;
```

And Homepage.js

```
import React from 'react';

const HomePage = () => (
    <>
    <h1>Hello, welcome to my blog!</h1>
    <p>
        Welcome to my blog! Proin congue
        ligula id risus posuere, vel eleifend ex egestas. Sed in turpis leo. 
        Aliquam malesuada in massa tincidunt egestas. Nam consectetur varius turpis, 
        non porta arcu porttitor non. In tincidunt vulputate nulla quis egestas. Ut 
        eleifend ut ipsum non fringilla. Praesent imperdiet nulla nec est luctus, at 
        sodales purus euismod.
    </p>
    <p>
        Donec vel mauris lectus. Etiam nec lectus urna. Sed sodales ultrices dapibus. 
        Nam blandit tristique risus, eget accumsan nisl interdum eu. Aenean ac accumsan 
        nisi. Nunc vel pulvinar diam. Nam eleifend egestas viverra. Donec finibus lectus 
        sed lorem ultricies, eget ornare leo luctus. Morbi vehicula, nulla eu tempor 
        interdum, nibh elit congue tellus, ac vulputate urna lorem nec nisi. Morbi id 
        consequat quam. Vivamus accumsan dui in facilisis aliquet.,
    </p>
    <p>
        Etiam nec lectus urna. Sed sodales ultrices dapibus. 
        Nam blandit tristique risus, eget accumsan nisl interdum eu. Aenean ac accumsan 
        nisi. Nunc vel pulvinar diam. Nam eleifend egestas viverra. Donec finibus lectus 
        sed lorem ultricies, eget ornare leo luctus. Morbi vehicula, nulla eu tempor 
        interdum, nibh elit congue tellus, ac vulputate urna lorem nec nisi. Morbi id 
        consequat quam. Vivamus accumsan dui in facilisis aliquet.,
    </p>
    </>
);

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `<Route path='/' element={HomePage} exact/>` with `<Route path='/' element={<HomePage/>} exact/>`.

You need to pass it as an element and not as a prop since react router v6.